# Game Over, Man...Game Over! - What's the source?

Tags: dialogue, aliens

> Game Over, Man...Game Over!

[image]

These iconic words were uttered by the late, great Bill Paxton in [***Aliens***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/).

BUT..they aren't the [**original script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Aliens_James_Cameron_May_28_1985_first_draft.html)

[image]

So...where did they come from?

**NB. "Official" sources from cast/crew only please....no speculation!**

Comment: As long as I remember, I saw some documentary about this line sayng these words were improvised on the spot

Comment: Bill Paxton improvised a few lines in Aliens, mostly the good ones. Mostly.

Comment: @Snowman "They mostly come at night.  Mostly." Excellent reference!

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2670/49).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It was the idea of Bill Paxton.

As it was told to [UPROXX](http://uproxx.com/hitfix/aliens-30-bill-paxton-recounts-the-origins-of-hudsons-most-famous-line/) by Bill Paxton himself,

(emphasis mine)

> I'm not great at improvising on the spot. The stuff I improvised was stuff that wasn't in the script, but it was stuff that I'd throw at Jim [Cameron] in a rehearsal.  Jim is a  — his mind's like a steel trap. He'd remember something I'd said when we were rehearsing at a scene we were shooting 2 months later. He'd say, 'You said something when we rehearsing to Sigourney. You said something about the express elevator to hell…put that in here.' That was kind of cool, that was kind of fun. 'Game over, man,' was really the background of the character.
>
> I figured…[Hudson] was kind of the enlisted version of Gorman who was the officer, [played by] Bill Hope. He probably came up on video games and back in those days you always … **I don't think they do it anymore because I don't play video games but it always at the end of your quarter, [it said] 'Game over.'…'Wow, has anybody ever used that, I wonder? Because it's good.' I had no idea it would catch on.**